# rotating an object with opticalflow?

Tags: c++, openframeworks, opticalflow

I am rather new to C++ and openframeworks. I am beginning to play with manipulating objects using the Lucas Kanade technique. I am having some success with pushing objects around but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to go about rotating them properly or even detect when rotational movement is occurring for that matter.

Does anyone have any pointers or tips they would like to share?

Many thanks,
N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the 2x3 affine transformation matrix of your motion could be a solution. The affine transformation matrix contains tranlational and rotational movements as far as scaling. If you are using OpenCV than cv::getAffineTransform is what you are looking for where you can directly input the tracked feature points.

Answer (score 2):

Optical flow calculations won't on their own help you detect things like "rotational movement". Basically, all the optical flow calc is doing is looking at changes pixel-by-pixel, while what you mean by rotation is a larger aggregate of pixel change. An algorithm would need to detect something like "all the pixels on the edge of the object are flowing in a (counter-)clockwise direction". Very difficult to do, and I don't think there's anything in OpenFrameworks or OpenCV that will help you.

Are you trying to detect rotation of an object in the image, or rotation-like movements in the image that will affect a virtual object? If it's the former, I think there are OpenCV techniques for identifying objects and then tracking them, including things like rotation. I think the things to research are like "opencv object tracking" and "opencv object motion analysis".

Comment: I was trying to use rotation-like movements in the image that will affect a virtual object. I think perhaps I will look into opencv's camshift, thanks.